# Underscore Code Not Understood

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In the following javascript code, (underscore library):

```
function getStudentInfo(elem, indx, list){
    //does stuff with them
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
    _.each(students,getStudentInfo);
}
```

students is an array looks like this

```
var students=[
{
"first":"Woody",
"stuff":"12",
}
//a lotta objects here
]
```

my question is in underscore _.each's call back function, (getStudentInfo) where does getStudentInfo know what the parameters are? What passed the parameters to it?

Comment: Did you read the docs?

http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: *"What passed the parameters to it?"* `_.each` does. You are passing a function to `_.each`, `_.each` calls that function. Which parameters are passed to the function is explained in the documentation.

Comment: Just consider that passing `getStudentInfo` as a parameter to `_.each` is (almost) identical to saying `function(elem, indx, list) { return getStudentInfo(elem, indx, list); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _.each(..) callback function takes 3 parameters

1. Element --> of the array / list
2. Index --> of the element in array / list
3. list --> The list iteself

you call _.each() by passing the list as first parameters and rest it takes care by passing the same into the callback functions one by one

_.each("The list / array", Callback Function)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the `_.each` function source code, It'll be like below snippet. where

**obj**: your array

**iteratee**: callback function

```
if (isArrayLike(obj)) { // checks for an array and it it is..
  for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) { // iterate over the array elements
    iteratee(obj[i], i, obj); // and pass each element to callback function
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you are doing operations on the array and for that most popular javacript library is lodash (which is known as '_').

callback function always returns a value which is individual element of array. it works same like as forEach loop of javascript.

refer https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#forEach

for its documentation

Comment: by using lodash we can achieve same functionality.